# Generating a Google Document file instead of a PDF

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script and coding in general. I want to use a ‘mail merge’ type of script to generate custom documents by populating a template document with data from a spreadsheet.
A script I found here is pretty much perfect: [Google Apps Script to create PDF](http://www.andrewroberts.net/2014/10/google-apps-script-create-pdf/),
except that it generates a PDF, rather than a Google Document file, which is what I need.

I have tried modifying this script to output a Google Document rather than a PDF, without success so far.

The relevant part of the original script is as follows:

```
// Create the PDF file, rename it if required and delete the doc copy
copyDoc.saveAndClose()
var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))  
if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {
newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME) 
} 
copyFile.setTrashed(true)
```

Specifically, I can't figure out a suitable modification for this line:

```
var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))
```

The closest I have gotten is to substitute the following, which only results in a blank document:

```
var newFile = DocumentApp.create(‘My_File_Name')
```

I'm sure there is an easy solution, but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your new document was created before the lines of code you're looking at, here:

```js
var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
```

The script then goes on to fill out the copy of the template, generate a PDF, and then *trash the document*. You just need to stop those last steps!

Change:

```js
// Create the PDF file, rename it if required and delete the doc copy

copyDoc.saveAndClose()

var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))  

if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {

  newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)
} 

copyFile.setTrashed(true)

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('New PDF file created in the root of your Google Drive')
```

...to...

```js
// Rename the file if desired, then close it
if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {
  copyDoc.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)
} 

copyDoc.saveAndClose()

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('New doc created in the root of your Google Drive')
```

When adapting code like this, it's helpful to also rename variables like `PDF_FILE_NAME` so they have meaning that is relevant to the updated code. But even without that, this simple change should do the trick.